# Controller not redirecting to my jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I've been reading other posts for hours related to this subject.
I will explain how it goes:

I Access recuperar.jsp, it is just 1 form to set the user's e-mail to recover password. It calls my LoginController.java - method (processaSenha).

At processaSenha method, I just send an email to the user with another JSP to be opened and set the new password. Here, my redirect does not work. I would like to redirect to confirmaregeracaosenha.jsp, this page just shows a message saying "ok, we sent you the email".

I created the get method for the pages, I did what I have been doing in many other controllers I have in my app.

LoginController:

```
package br.com.kolss.boxml.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.kolss.boxml.dto.RegeraSenhaDTO;
import br.com.kolss.boxml.entidades.Usuario;
import br.com.kolss.boxml.service.ContatoService;
import br.com.kolss.boxml.service.LoginService;
import br.com.kolss.boxml.service.UsuarioService;
import br.com.kolss.boxml.util.Util;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
protected LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
protected ContatoService contatoService;

@Autowired
private UsuarioService usuarioService;

protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {

    logger.debug("LoginController.login");      

    return new ModelAndView("login");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/primeiroacesso",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView primeiroacesso() {

    logger.debug("LoginController.primeiroacesso");

    return new ModelAndView("primeiroacesso");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/recuperar",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView recuperarSenha() {

    logger.debug("LoginController.recuperar");

    return new ModelAndView("recuperar");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/regeraSenha", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json"})
public ModelAndView processaSenha(@RequestBody RegeraSenhaDTO regeraSenhaDTO, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{   

    logger.debug("LoginController.regeraSenha"); 
    StringBuffer fullURI = request.getRequestURL();
    String pathDoUriDeEnvioParaOEmail = fullURI.toString().split("/")[2];
    loginService.regeraSenhaDoUsuario(regeraSenhaDTO.getEmail(), "", pathDoUriDeEnvioParaOEmail);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/confirmacaoEmailSenha");     

}   

@RequestMapping(value="/confirmacaoEmailSenha",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView regeracao() {

    logger.debug("LoginController.confirmacaoEmailSenha");

    return new ModelAndView("confirmacaoEmailSenha");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/confirmacaoNovaSenha",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView confirmacaoNovaSenha() {

    logger.debug("LoginController.confirmacaoNovaSenha");

    return new ModelAndView("confirmacaoNovaSenha");
}


@RequestMapping(value="/login/salvar", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView salvaSenhaPrimeiroAcesso(@RequestBody RegeraSenhaDTO regeraSenhaDTO){ 

    final Usuario usuario = usuarioService.obterUsuarioPorEmail(regeraSenhaDTO.getEmail()); 
    if(regeraSenhaDTO.getNovaSenha().equals(regeraSenhaDTO.getConfirmaSenha())){
        String cryptPassword = Util.criptografarSenha(regeraSenhaDTO.getNovaSenha());
        usuario.setSenha(cryptPassword);            
        loginService.insereNovaSenha(usuario);  
    }           

    return new ModelAndView("login");

    }

}
```

Tiles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/restrict/template/default/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/restrict/template/default/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/restrict/template/default/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/template/default/body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/restrict/template/default/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="homePrimeiroAcesso" template="/primeiroacesso.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeTemplate" template="/restrict/template/home/home.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeContato" template="/restrict/template/home/contato.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeLogin" template="/login.jsp"/>    
<definition name="homeRecuperaSenha" template="/restrict/template/home/recuperar.jsp"/>  
<definition name="homeNoticiaUm" template="/restrict/template/home/noticia-1.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeNoticiaDois" template="/restrict/template/home/noticia-2.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeNoticiaTres" template="/restrict/template/home/noticia-3.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeNoticiaQuatro" template="/restrict/template/home/noticia-4.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeNoticiaCinco" template="/restrict/template/home/noticia-5.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeNoticias" template="/restrict/template/home/noticias.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeConfirmacaoEmailSenha" template="/confirmaregeracaosenha.jsp"/>
<definition name="homeConfirmacaoNovaSenha" template="/confirmanovasenha.jsp"/>

<definition name="confirmacaoNovaSenha" extends="homeConfirmacaoNovaSenha"/>
<definition name="confirmacaoEmailSenha" extends="homeConfirmacaoEmailSenha"/>
<definition name="contato" extends="homeContato"/>
<definition name="primeiroacesso" extends="homePrimeiroAcesso"/>  
<definition name="home" extends="homeTemplate"/>    
<definition name="login" extends="homeLogin"/>
<definition name="recuperar" extends="homeRecuperaSenha"/>
<definition name="noticiaUm" extends="homeNoticiaUm"/>
<definition name="noticiaDois" extends="homeNoticiaDois"/>
<definition name="noticiaTres" extends="homeNoticiaTres"/>
<definition name="noticiaQuatro" extends="homeNoticiaQuatro"/>
<definition name="noticiaCinco" extends="homeNoticiaCinco"/>
<definition name="noticias" extends="homeNoticias"/>   

<definition name="organizacao" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/organizacao.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="cliente" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/cliente.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="cadastrosusuarios" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/cadastrosusuarios.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="tipoxml" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/tipoxml.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="statusnfecte" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/statusnfecte.jsp" />
</definition>   

<definition name="auxiliaresregras" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/auxiliaresregras.jsp" />
</definition>   

<definition name="auxiliaresmenu" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/auxiliaresmenu.jsp" />
</definition>   

<definition name="configuracoesbasicas" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/configuracoesbasicas.jsp" />
</definition>   

<definition name="auxiliaresperfil" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/auxiliaresperfil.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="configuracaodoemail" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/cadastros/configuracaodoemail.jsp" />
</definition> 

<definition name="consultaextrato" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/consultas/consultaextrato.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="monitorxml" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/consultas/monitorxml.jsp" />
</definition> 

<definition name="monitornotas" extends="defaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/restrict/view/consultas/monitornotas.jsp" />
</definition> 


</tiles-definitions>
```

recuperar.jsp:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>

  <!-- META CONFIGURATION -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="description" content="boXml é uma ferramenta desenvolvida pela Kolss especialmente para as empresas que necessitam de uma automatização em armazenamento e organização de XML." />   
  <meta name="keywords" content="boxml, xml, armazenamento, organização, sistema, kolss" />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- OPEN GRAPH META -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Armazenamos e organizamos seus XMLs. Faça um teste grátis!"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="restrict/resources/images/boxml_og.png"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="boXml"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Uma ferramenta desenvolvida especialmente para as empresas que necessitam de uma automatização em armazenamento e organização de XML."/>
  <!-- // --> 

  <!-- WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT -->
  <meta name="author" content="Brício Fernandes" />
  <meta name="reply-to" content="bricioweb@gmail.com" />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- FAVICON -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="restrict/resources/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- TITLE -->
  <title>Recuperar senha | boXml - Solução em Armazenamento de XMLs</title>
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- CSS LIBRARY -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/foundation/foundation.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/icons/flaticon.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/styles/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/simptip.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/introloader/introLoader.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/slick.css" />

  <!-- SCRIPT LIBRARY -->
  <script src="restrict/js/jqueryNovoTemplate/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- MODERNIZR - FOUNDATION -->
  <script src="restrict/js/foundation/modernizr.js"></script>
  <!-- // --> 

 </head>

 <body id="login" ng-controller="RegeraSenhaController" data-ng-app="BoxApp">

  <!-- INTRO LOADER -->
  <div id="intro"></div>
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- SECTION "CONTACT" -->
  <section id="recuperar" class="section">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="small-11 small-centered medium-7 medium-centered large-5 large-centered columns">
       
       <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">
         <div class="padding-logo">
          <img src="restrict/resources/images/boxml_logomarca_invert.png" title="boXml - Solução em armazenamento de XMLs" width="133" height="35"/>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      
       <form id="form-recuperar">
       
       <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
         <label>Informe seu e-mail:
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
         </label>
        </div>       
       </div>      
       
       <div class="row" style="padding-top:11px">      
        <div class="small-12 small-centered medium-12 medium-centered large-12 large-centered columns">                    
          <input ng-click="regeraSenha()" id="btn" style="width:100%" title="Clique para gerar uma senha" class="submit button expand btn-action btn-green btn-big" type="submit" value="Gerar nova senha" />
        </div>     
       </div>
       
        
      </form>  

       <div class="row"> 
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">        
         <div class="login-footer">
          Lembrou a senha? <a href="login" title="Clique para fazer login"><b>Faça login</b></a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      
      
      </div>
     </div>
     
   

  </section>

 <!-- // -->
 <!-- SCRIPT LIBRARY -->
 <script src="restrict/js/foundation/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="restrict/js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>

 <!-- BEGIN CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-touch.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script
  src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ocLazyLoad.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script
  src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/ngMask.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- END CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->

 <script src="restrict/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="restrict/js/controllers/RegeraSenhaController.js"></script>
 <script src="restrict/js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
 <!-- // -->


 <script>
  // FOUNDATION LOAD
  $(document).foundation();
 </script>

 </body>
 
</html>
```

confirmaregeracaosenha.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<!-- META CONFIGURATION -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
 <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="description"
   content="boXml é uma ferramenta desenvolvida pela Kolss especialmente para as empresas que necessitam de uma automatização em armazenamento e organização de XML." />
  <meta name="keywords"
   content="boxml, xml, armazenamento, organização, sistema, kolss" />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- OPEN GRAPH META -->
  <meta property="og:title"
   content="Armazenamos e organizamos seus XMLs. Faça um teste grátis!" />
  <meta property="og:image"
   content="restrict/resources/images/boxml_og.png" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="boXml" />
  <meta property="og:description"
   content="Uma ferramenta desenvolvida especialmente para as empresas que necessitam de uma automatização em armazenamento e organização de XML." />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- // -->

  <!-- FAVICON -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="restrict/resources/images/favicon.ico"
   type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- TITLE -->
  <title>Atualizar senha | boXml - Solução em Armazenamento de
   XMLs</title> <!-- // -->

  <!-- CSS LIBRARY -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
   href="restrict/resources/css/foundation/foundation.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet"
   href="restrict/resources/css/icons/flaticon.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/styles/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/simptip.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet"
   href="restrict/resources/css/introloader/introLoader.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restrict/resources/css/slick.css" />
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- SCRIPT LIBRARY -->
  <script src="restrict/js/jqueryNovoTemplate/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- // -->

  <!-- MODERNIZR - FOUNDATION -->
  <script src="restrict/js/foundation/modernizr.js"></script>
  <!-- // -->
</head>

<body id="login" data-ng-app="BoxApp">

 <!-- INTRO LOADER -->
 <div id="intro"></div>
 <!-- // -->

 <!-- SECTION "CONTACT" -->
 <section id="login" class="section">
 <div class="row">
  <div
   class="small-11 small-centered medium-7 medium-centered large-5 large-centered columns">

   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">
     <div class="padding-logo">
      <img src="restrict/resources/images/boxml_logomarca_invert.png"
       title="boXml - Solução em armazenamento de XMLs" width="133"
       height="35" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <form id="formLogin" method="POST" action=""
    class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="formLogin" novalidate>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">

      <label><center>Um email com as informações
        necessárias para regeração da senha da sua conta foi enviado
        para a conta de e-mail atrelada a aplicação.</center></label> 
      <div id="footer" class="footer" align="center"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center">
     <div class="login-footer clearfix">
      <span class="left"> <a href="recuperar"
       title="Clique para recuperar sua senha"><b>Esqueceu a
         senha?</b></a>
      </span>
      <div class="partner right">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.geotrust.com/" target="_blank"
         title="Secured by GeoTrust"><img
          src="restrict/resources/images/geotrust.png" width="151"
          height="37" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://aws.amazon.com/pt/" target="_blank"
         title="Amazon Web services"><img
          src="restrict/resources/images/amazon.png" width="126"
          height="47" /></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>



 </section>


 <!-- SCRIPT LIBRARY -->
 <script src="restrict/js/foundation/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="restrict/js/foundation/foundation.min.js"></script>

 <!-- BEGIN CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-touch.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script
  src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ocLazyLoad.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script
  src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/global/plugins/angularjs/ngMask.min.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- END CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->

 <script src="restrict/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!-- // -->

 <script>
  // FOUNDATION LOAD
  $(document).foundation();  
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!--
<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>-->

<bean id="viewResolver"  
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">  
    <property name="viewClass">  
        <value>  
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView  
        </value>  
    </property>  
</bean>     
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"  
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">  
    <property name="definitions">  
        <list>  
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>  
        </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

ScreenShots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4FAD.jpg

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your viewResolver? is it a tilesViewResolver or something else. Looks like you are using tiles for your views. Please look at the below link and hope that might help..http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-mvc-and-apache-tiles-integration-example/

Comment: Hello, tks for the reply.. I posted my viewResolver and I am going to check the link you passed now. Thanks

Comment: Well... The configuration with tiles is running ok... I've read this link before. Thanks anyway

Comment: why don't you open a Javascript based modal instead of redirecting to a new JSP ? It might solve your issue

Comment: what is exactly happening?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is changing the return type of method "processaSenha" to String and return just "redirect:/url/to/go".

Comment: What happens if you do that?

Comment: Is keeps in the same screen... does nothing.

Comment: Try it without "produces={"application/json"}" in the method annotation of "processaSenha"